# Django - Get First image from Foreign related table in Django 3.1

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-orm

please I am using Django 3.1 and I am trying to figure out, how to get one image from the foreign table - in home view - there should be cards with all vehicles and only first image for each one - as a thumbnail.

Here is my models.py:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    ...

    def first_image(self):
       return self.image_set.first()

class Image(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

In my template, I am trying to get the first image of a Vehicle by:

```
{% for v in vehicles %}
   <img src="{{ v.first_image.image.url }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

I have also tried *{{ v.first_image.url }}* but nothing works.
I tried to add a print function to first_image (same as return - self.image_set.first()) and it is getting **None**, or **catalog.Image.None**

When I am printing all images for one vehicle, it works perfectly via:

```
{% for i in images %}
   <img src="{{ i.image.url }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Vehicle, Image


def home_view(request):
    vehicles = Vehicle.objects.all()
    context = {
        'vehicles': vehicles,
    }
    print(context)
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)

def vehicle_detail_view(request, slug_make, slug_model, slug_vehicle):
    vehicle = Vehicle.objects.get(
        make__slug=slug_make, model__slug=slug_model, slug=slug_vehicle)
    images = Image.objects.filter(vehicle=vehicle)
    context = {
        'vehicle': vehicle,
        'images': images
    }
    return render(request, 'vehicle_detail.html', context)
```

I don't know, how to figure this out, I only guess to create another field in Vehicle table, and call it **thumbnail**.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, I just made a mistake, when I was limiting:

```
def home_view(request):
    vehicles = Vehicle.objects.all()[:1]
```

I am sorry for that